# "I first tasted" vs "I had my first taste of"

Tags: grammar, phrase-requests

Which version is more grammatical or idiomatic?

Example sentences:

> **I first tasted** this cake on my wedding.
>
> **I had my first taste** **of** this cake on my wedding.

Or maybe they mean slightly different things?

Comment: The second has a stronger implication that it is the very same exact cake. (e.g. Maybe you froze what was left)  And it’s either ***on*** my wedding day, or ***at*** my wedding (i. e.  the event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To have a first taste of something* is an idiom with a special meaning, in addition to the literal meaning, which is equivalent to tasting something for the first time.

Unfortunately, I haven't found documentation of the idiom, but here's an example:

> I adopted Charlotte at the age of four from a woman who had kept her as an indoor cat in a tiny house.  Charlotte had never gone outside in her previous home, and for her first year living with me she was a nervous Nellie and felt no temptation to go outside.  But one day she became curious and ran out as someone was coming inside.  She didn't come back until she was good and ready, and once she had had **her first taste of freedom**, it became a battle to keep her inside.  The problem wasn't solved until I moved to a street with less traffic and I was comfortable letting her go out every day.

If you google "first taste of," you'll find song lyrics such as "First Taste of Texas," "First Taste of Sin," and "First Taste of Hurt."  These are things that no one is *eating*.

Your sentences are equivalent, however.

(You could fix "on my wedding": either "on my wedding day" or "at my wedding.")

Answer (score 0):

Neither, you cannot be "on your wedding." You can be at your wedding, but you can't be on your wedding. Other than that they are both correct.

Comment: It could have been *on* your wedding *day* though.